# Crystal Report Logon Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am getting error while opening Crystal Report  from my **asp.net** application at production server. Credentials are define in `web.config`. In `web.config` we have `userid`, `password`, `server` and `database name`.
here is the error:

> Logon failed. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: ADODB.Connection
>   Description: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
>   installed. Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\OrderAudit
>   {5A4491A4-BFD5-4EA4-8806-94A7CED3467A}.rpt: Unable to connect:
>   incorrect log on parameters.

When I connected to my production database server from my localhost reports are opening okay. 
any solution?

Comment: can you run the report on the production server in crystal reports? it may be a config error somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal is trying to tell you that the ADO database provider is not installed on the machine.

For example, if you are connecting to an Oracle database, then the Oracle driver needs to be installed on the ASP.Net server.

Comment: It can be nastier than that. If you used (for example) the 2008 version of the SQL Native driver when creating the report, the 2005 version won't work. Check the database properties of the report and check that the driver named there is available.

Comment: SQL Native Client Was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install sqlncli.msi (SQL Native Client driver) from 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15748